# Why not added related objects? (entity-framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```cs
using (var context = new EF6RecipesContext())
{
   // add an artist with two albums
   var artist = new Artist { FirstName = "Alan", LastName = "Jackson" };
   var album1 = new Album { AlbumName = "Drive" };
   var album2 = new Album { AlbumName = "Live at Texas Stadium" };
   artist.Albums.Add(album1);
   artist.Albums.Add(album2);
   context.Artists.Add(artist);
   // add an album for two artists
   var artist1 = new Artist { FirstName = "Tobby", LastName = "Keith" };
   var artist2 = new Artist { FirstName = "Merle", LastName = "Haggard" };
   var album = new Album { AlbumName = "Honkytonk University" };
   artist1.Albums.Add(album);
   artist2.Albums.Add(album);
   context.Albums.Add(album);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
using (var context = new EF6RecipesContext())
{
   Console.WriteLine("Artists and their albums...");
   var artists = context.Artists;
   foreach (var artist in artists)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", artist.FirstName, artist.LastName);
      foreach (var album in artist.Albums)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", album.AlbumName);
      }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("\nAlbums and their artists...");
   var albums = context.Albums;
   foreach (var album in albums)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", album.AlbumName);
      foreach (var artist in album.Artists)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1}", artist.FirstName, artist.LastName);
      }
   }
}
```

I get the following result of my program (see, please, screenshot):

[image]

In the book there is a different result.

[image]

Explanation of the author:

> Next we create and initialize a couple of instances of the Artist entity type and an >instance of the Album entity type. Because the two artists collaborated on the album, we >add the album to both artists Albums navigation property (which is of type >EntityCollection). Adding the album to the Database Context causes the artists to get 
>   added as well.

If we added the album (“Honkytonk University”), it should be automatically added 2 related artist (“Tobby” and “Merle”). But they will not be added (I looked in the database). Why?

Comment: Try context.Artists.Add(artist1); context.Artists.Add(artist2) instead of context.Albums.Add(album) before your context.SaveChanges()

Comment: Yes. Thanks your answer. It works, but why is not working example of the author's books?

Comment: Dont know why the example doesnt work but you cant add an album to artists that don't exist in your context